# Taking #define value from the user

Tags: c, struct

how is it possible to take the #define value from the user input instead of pre-defining it in a code when structures are involved.Given the code below, I would like to take the value N from the user, is it possible or should I try something else

```
#define N 4

// Data structure to store graph
struct Graph {
    // An array of pointers to Node to represent adjacency list
    struct Node* head[N];
};
```

Comment: Who is the user? Someone using binary executable or the user refers to other developers who will compile the library?

Comment: you will have to dynamically allocate the memory for `head`

Comment: Oh, seriously guys? It's pretty clear what he tries to do. It's also clear that he's a beginner so he doesn't know about dynamic memory allocation, so please cut him some slack and help him ... instead of asking impertinent questions that might confuse him further.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in the way you are trying to do. You cannot dynamically (run-time) redefine a type in C.
One alternative could be to store a double pointer and allocate memory according to what the user asks.

Change the Graph struct to the following:

```
// Data structure to store graph
struct Graph {
    // A double pointer to Node to represent adjacency list
    struct Node** head;
};
```

Now, depending on the value N, you could dynamically allocate the memory required.

```
int N = 4;
Graph g;
g.head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*) * N);
```

Here, `N` can equally well be a #define or a variable set at run-time. The rest of your code could remain the same. You can continue to use `g.head[i]` to refer to the i'th element, just like you would if you had an array.

Of course, don't forget to `free()` the allocated memory when you are done or you will have a leak!

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible at runtime. #define macros are replaced and determined at compilation time, so predetermined at runtime. You would have to receive the user input into a variable, and dynamically allocate your **head** array.

However as was implied in one of the comments. You can use the -D flag at compilation time to set a value to the macro. So you could create a script that takes a value from the user and run something like:

gcc -DN=$userinput ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. However, the compiler provides preprocessor controlling options. For e.g. `gcc` compiler has an option [-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> -D name=definition
>       The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a '#define' directive....

For e.g. consider this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
#ifdef N
    printf ("N: %d\n", N);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code:

```
#gcc -DN=10 -Wall -Wextra pp.c
```

the `-DN=10` is equivalent to `#define N 10`

Run:

```
#./a.out
N: 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to read more about dynamic allocation, for example from here:
https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html

As a small example taken from the above link:

```
// declare a pointer variable to point to allocated heap space
int    *p_array;

// call malloc to allocate that appropriate number of bytes for the array

p_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);      // allocate 50 ints

// always CHECK RETURN VALUE of functions and HANDLE ERROR return values
// here is one example of handling an unrecoverable malloc error 
// (other error handling code is removed from this document for readability):
if(p_array == NULL) {
  printf("malloc of size %d failed!\n", 50);   // could also call perror here
  exit(1);   // or return an error to caller
}


// use [] notation to access array buckets 
// (THIS IS THE PREFERED WAY TO DO IT)
for(i=0; i < 50; i++) {
  p_array[i] = 0;
}
```

Also read the `malloc` docs:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc